# Why when i restart the shell, java is unavailable?

Tags: macos, bash

I have installed java 1.7 on my mac, and I have edited ~/.bash_profile as the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Content    s/Home
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

When I execute `source /.bash_profile`, the java become available. But when I restart the shell, I got the following error message:

```
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

I have to re-execute `source /.bash_profile` to make it available.

I am so confused, hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is because variables you export are only valid in the current ssh session.

Look here for deeper explanation:

[Mac OS X 10.9 - setting permanent environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502759/mac-os-x-10-9-setting-permanent-environment-variables)

As @trojanfoe stated there:

> The **.bash_profile** is only executed for a login-shell, whereas **.bashrc**
>   is executed for every new shell instance

Comment: After I used **.bashrc**, it didn't resolve. I think it's because I installed JRE, NOT JDK. After I install a jdk version, it can work well. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773051/how-to-make-os-x-to-read-bash-profile-not-profile-file) out please. I don't believe your problem is a JAVA problem but it looks rather misunderstanding on BASH side.