# How to store api keys as variables via the terminal - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to store my api keys in a variable via the terminal but i am unsure why it is not saving/storing my api keys.

- for example, in the terminal when i type the below:

  `export GMAIL_USERNAME="myname@gmail.com"`
- then when i type in `env` i can see the varaibale has been stored:
  [image]
- but when i restart my terminal the variable `GMAIL_USERNAME="myname@gmail.com"` is no longer there

> could one tell me where i am going wrong? all i would like to do is
>   store in development my api secret keys in a variable. your help would
>   be much appreciated

Comment: why don't you add that key into `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: could you advise how this is done. or direct me to the right documentation that shows one how to do so

Comment: sure thing, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502759/mac-os-x-10-9-setting-permanent-environment-variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can persist environment variables by adding them to a script that gets called on shell startup, that approach has a few problems.

The biggest problem is that they are available globally across your shell, and not scoped to a project.
What happens if you have another project, and want to use a different gmail account?

A better solution is using [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or [direnv](https://direnv.net/) and set those environment variables for the current project only.

Comment: didn't know about these solutions. It might become a problem, as you said, if OP decides to have another projects with the same env var, but, in that case I think it'll be easier just to drop that var into the environment file in the rails project (and set a different value per env, one for dev, one for prod and so on)