# how to set set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable in mac

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

[image]

I had set create .bash_profile file and save these lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

and then enter in terminal: source ~/.bash_profile
and if I enter in terminal this command: echo $ANDROID_HOME 
I have the correct path:

```
/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk
```

but If I run command:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

in my ionic project, I got this error:

```
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Android SDK not found. Make 
sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set 
the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

what should I do!

Comment: I'm working on Linux, you should put your path to android it in ~/.bashr, but this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: @DenisSolakovic in mac I put in ~/.bash_profile but it get me the same error

Comment: Did you use the command source: source ~/.bashrc, after changing the file?

Comment: This should be in your bashrc:
`export ANDROID_HOME=/your/path/to/android
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Comment: @DenisSolakovic: yes I did the i set path as above and use command source ~/.bashrc but the same issue

Comment: One more thing, I had a similar problem, using the zsh instead of bash.

Comment: @DenisSolakovic what is zsh and how can I use it

Comment: Don't bother with it right now, it's just a fancy bash. It doesen't have anything to do with the problem you're facing

Comment: @DenisSolakovic ok Thanks for help

Comment: Try to re-download both tools and platform tools into another directory, and then setup your bashrc directly in bashrc file, not bash_profile, although it has to work in both

Comment: @DenisSolakovic is it true to create the both files I didn't find any of them so I touch them and write my variables?

Comment: Bashrc should exist, try reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502759/mac-os-x-10-9-setting-permanent-environment-variables

Comment: Another useful thing (that is when you get this sorted out) is to set:
export PATH=$PATH:/your/path/to/android/gradle/bin

Comment: @DenisSolakovic I used the both files and set the variables there, I type nav command in the terminal and I found my ANDROID_HOME=/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk & PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/macbookpro/L

Comment: @DenisSolakovic is that line correct: export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools ?