# How to set custom Environment variable on Mac?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, operating-system, environment-variables

I have a requirement where I need to set a custom environment variable called `CLUSTER_ENV = '@fooURL'`
The steps I have followed are:

1. Open terminal, open `bash_profile` and save `CLUSTER_ENV='@foo'`. When I do `echo $CLUSTER_ENV` , I get blank output.
2. I did the same thing in the `bashrc` file and in this case, the `$CLUSTER_ENV` shows the value only when I run it in the same terminal window.

Which is the best or recommended way to permanently set the environment variable on a Mac?
Im running El Capitan.

I have gone through these links for reference:

http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/28/set-enviornment-variables-mac-os-x/

[Mac OS X 10.9 - setting permanent environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502759/mac-os-x-10-9-setting-permanent-environment-variables)

Comment: bash_profile and bashrc will only work (by default) if you actually use bash. I assume you know and made sure you run bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will normally do on any Linux distro: export CLUSTER_ENV=my.url.com which will have to be added to ~/.bash_profile