# Environment variable is not set MacOS

Tags: macos, environment-variables, zsh

I need to set environment variables to build an Ionic application, open the terminal and run the command:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
```

Without closing the terminal I type echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, and the environment variable is returned perfectly, so I run "source ~/.bash_profile", to update the environment variables. I open and close the terminal and my environment variable is empty!
I tried to set it manually by opening the environment variables files, with a text editor but without success.

Comment: Sourcing a file does not update *it* from the current environment.

Comment: Aside from the fact that I don't quite get why you are sourcing .bash_profile, when you run zsh - this by itself already begs for trouble -, I wonder whether you have put this `export` statement into your .bash_profile. Do a `set -x` before sourcing the file, to see what actually happens in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For macOS 10.15 Catalina and Newer, you need to use a `.zshenv` file instead of `.bash_profile`. This is because, by default since Catalina, the terminal uses `zsh` instead of bash.

Export paths permanently in the following manner:
Create `.zshenv` file:

```
touch ~/.zshenv
open -a TextEdit.app ~/.zshenv
```

Type out the export you want to do in this format:

`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk`

and save it. (From this old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502759/mac-os-x-10-9-setting-permanent-environment-variables/71491049#71491049))

Comment: TextEdit.app 